# Disable page forwarding in Android webview

Tags: android, redirect, webview

I have a webview that shows ads (not my ads), the problem is when user clicks the "x" button to exit the ad, the ad still directs them to a site. What I wonder is since I can't control the ads, can I instead Disable page directing/forwarding inside webview? that means even if user clicks a link inside my webview nothing should happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`WebClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideKeyEvent%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method.

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
       //True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
       return true;
   }
 });
```

Comment: method is not getting called on android 4.4 for local webpages

Answer (score 1):

### You can build undetected webview build-id adblocker

I know it is too late for answering this question, however, for the sake of others who have the same question.

Well, you can build webview build-id adblocker, if you wish to prevent ads from loading, and provide smooth experience to the users, I am confident, because I have already implemented it in may app.

**The Idea**

Is to have a black list of all possible ad-serves domain name, then while webview load resources, you will prevent loading from black list domains. so it depends on how many ads-serves domain you have in the black list, fortunately, there is one website ([**pgl.yoyo.org/as/**](https://pgl.yoyo.org/as/)) which provide you with a very long list of ad-serves domai names, and listed them in many flavoures.
you can read [**this**](https://www.hidroh.com/2016/05/19/hacking-up-ad-blocker-android/) article for:

> [how to implement  webview build-id adblocker](https://www.hidroh.com/2016/05/19/hacking-up-ad-blocker-android/)

, you will build it %100 as long as you follow step by step instructions.

> A summary of what we need to do:

- Get the list of ad hostnames from pgl.yoyo.org.
- Save the list somewhere, load it when application starts.
- Use`WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(WebView, String)` to intercept
  requests.
- Check if the request URL belongs to one of the hostnames in
  the list and override it, returning a dummy resource instead of the
  actual one, which is supposed to be ads

Answer (score 0):

I tried using shouldOverrideUrlLoading, but it didn't work. It looks like that this method is called only once when the html is loaded. After that, you click a link but the method is no more invoked.

I am also making a WebView embedding Youtube Player. Instead of forwarding ads redirect from the WebView, I prefer to open ads in a browser. So I override onLoadResource method:

```html
     @Override
     public void onLoadResource(final WebView view, final String url) {
      if(url.indexOf("googleadservices.")>-1){
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
       view.stopLoading();
       view.postDelayed(
         new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
           Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
           Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
           i.setClassName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
           startActivity(i);
          }
         }
           ,100
          );
      }
     }
```

It worked. When I clicked the ads link, a new browser is opened in which ads site is displayed well, and the WebView was not redirected. When I push the return button, WebView show up again and I can continue watching video.

But there were still problems. If I repeat opening browser and returning to WebView for many times, the WebView might fail to block redirecting to the ads site. It is just redirected to the ads site. If I am lucky I could repeat opening and returning for 100 times. But sometimes It failed just when I repeat several times. I don't know why.

Does anyboday have any idea about how to improve it? Or is there another way to disable ads redirect?