# How disable redirect in WebView?

Tags: android, redirect, webview

In WebView, I open the website page for the desktop. The site, apparently, the width of the screen determines that the mobile phone and redirects to the mobile version. How disable redirect in WebView?
TARGET PAGE: https://www.olx.ua/myaccount/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHjEJ.png)

Comment: Maybe this question's answer can help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151339/disable-page-forwarding-in-android-webview

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the userAgent in the webview to use Desktop version by adding one or more setting to your Webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do as below.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        webView.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Pease check the url with your original url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

```
@Override 
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
    if (url.equals(originalUrl)) { 
        view.loadUrl(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```